# UPS monitoring for Linux?

Tags: monitoring, ups

I'm bit worried where to post this question, however, i expect that people engaged with servers should have some tip for me.

I have got this ups: http://www.fsp-europe.com/ep850.php

And since it should be placed in a box outdoor where temperatures can reach ~40c i would like to be able to monitor it somehow.

There, on that remote location, i have only single board computers with linux.

My question is: Is there any simple to use monitoring tool for linux. Without GUI! And, with a support to monitor it via USB?

I generally don't know if there is some common monitoring protocol for UPS devices?

Comment: Mario, why are you placing batteries in a high-temp environment? Battery life expectancy is significantly shortened... Please also note that a box left in the sun will inevitably experience much higher temps which are outside the vendor-approved range (0-40 centigrade).

Comment: @DeerHunter It's not constantly that hot but during the summer, i know that temperatures can reach 40c (the limit for the UPS i have). I have been thinking about relay which will switch from power through UPS to direct power. (So i would loose UPS if it is over 40c) but at least i would be able to protect battery.

It seems that UPS doesn't have the option to do it inside :) It's not likely to have such option :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://www.networkupstools.org/) should help you get started, it will likely be possible to install it onto your systems and may even be packaged for your distributions.  I don't know if your device is supported however.